# Ip routing Linux subnet to an external IP

Tags: linux, networking, routing, route, iproute

Good morning

I have a scenario where an application makes a request to service A on IP 10.244.5.0 which is not really in use. The goal is to send all request of a subnet (where the service A IP is part of) to another application (Service B) on a public IP. This application then redirects everything originally directed to the IP of Service A(10.244.5.0) to a different endpoint based on internal mapping rules. While the redirection in the external application works, I'm not able to route the request to the subnet to this external IP.

I tried to use the IP route command but this does not work.

`sudo ip route add <public Ip service B> dev ens3`

`sudo ip route add 10.70.0.0/16 via <public Ip service B> dev ens3`

So, in general, I need a way to route each request from this machine to the subnet 10.70.0.0/16 routed to a public IP in a different environment without losing the original destination address.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You should add a(n ascii) schematic of what you are describing to help understand the goal. And give an complete example from the very first system to the very last system with everything involved in-between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do that without some kind of [tunnel](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/17/an-introduction-to-linux-virtual-interfaces-tunnels#).

The gateway (the address after "via") *must* be accessible on L2 level, i.e. being on the same subnet (normally, or a p-2-p link).